# Как использовать return вместо echo

Tags: php, laravel

Начал изучать php фреймворк laravel и обратил внимание, что для вывода текста достаточно писать:

```
return "Hello World!";
```

вместо аналогичного на php:

```
echo "Hello World!";
```

Как это работает? Сначала думал, что это делается каким-то хитрым способом через буфер, например:

```
ob_start();

function my() {
    return "Hello World!";
}

my();

ob_get_contents();
```

Но такой вариант не работает. Как это работает?

Comment: Ну Вы же это выводите в blade view или где-то в другом месте?

Comment: `$var = include "file.php";`

Comment: Если просто прописать Route::get('/', function() { return 'Hello World!' }); то тоже все работает (без blade).

Comment: это всего лишь обозначает, что в итоге где то есть условный `$result = route(..); echo $result;`

Comment: Если использовать echo, тогда получается, что при определенной ситуации фреймворк должен возвращать ошибку, например: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Object could not be converted to string, но этого не происходит.

Comment: @Антон Нельзя использовать echo! Поймите вы уже, что в ларавеле есть Response, post хуки и middleware которые используют response для вторичной обработки ответа! Убивая их, вы убиваете кучу механизмов фреймворка!!!!!!! Если вы не хотите действовать по механизмам фреймворка, то тогда лучше полностью откажитесь от его изучения и используйте код на коленке!!! Этим вы сэкономите нервы себе и людям.

Comment: @EugeneX спасибо за подробный ответ, теперь стало понятно. Я не использую echo в Laravel, а задаю этот вопрос с целью разобраться в более глубоких и тонких механизмах фреймворка, чтобы разобраться в том, как он работает на низком уровне (что использует под капотом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, кому-то это будет полезно. Для реализации необходимо записывать данные в поток OutputStream. Здесь можно ознакомиться с потоками ввода / вывода (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php).

Теперь к самой реализации.

```
/**
*   Здесь может быть функция или метод класса
*/
function test() {
    return "Hello World!";
}

/**
*   Открываем поток OutputStream для записи данных
*/
$outputStream = fopen('php://output', 'a');

/**
*   Отправляем http код ответа (в данном случае это будет статус 200 - ОК)
*/
http_response_code(200);

/**
*   Устанавливаем заголовок, чтобы данные отображались в html
*/
header('Content-Type: text/html');

/**
*   Записываем данные в поток вывода (OutputStream)
*   в нашем случае передаем вторым аргументом нашу функцию
*/
fwrite($outputStream, test());

/**
*   Закрываем поток для записи
*/
fclose($outputStream);
```

Получаем результат на странице

```
Hello World!
```

Answer (score 3):

Как вы молодёжь любите себе жизнь усложнять :)

Открываем документацию : https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/responses

И что мы там видим :

> Все маршруты и контроллеры должны возвращать ответ, который будет отправлен обратно в браузер пользователя. Laravel предлагает несколько разных способов вернуть ответы. Самый простой ответ – это возврат строки из маршрута или контроллера. Фреймворк автоматически преобразует строку в полный HTTP-ответ:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

> **(!!!) Все маршруты и контроллеры должны возвращать ответ, который будет отправлен обратно в браузер пользователя. (!!!)**

Никаких вам echo! Забудьте! Вы ломаете все механизмы Response, Хуков и Middleware!!!

Если вы хотите выводить HTML то используйте Blade https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/blade

**Если лезь глубоко под капот**, то  по факту твоя строка преобразуется в

`Illuminate\Support\Stringable`

А от туда уже создаёться объект `Illuminate\Http\Response`

`$response = new Response($response->__toString(), 200, ['Content-Type' => 'text/html']);`

**Всё это описано в классе:**
`Illuminate\Routing\Router` в методе `toResponse`

- https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_toResponse